# Jump to finally without exiting a function/procedure

Tags: delphi

I have the following situation:

```
procedure Test;
begin
 repeat
  TryAgain := FALSE;
  try
   // Code
   // Code
   if this and that then begin
    TryAgain := TRUE;
    exit;
   end;
  finally
   // CleanUpCode
  end;
 until TryAgain = FALSE;
end;
```

How can I jump to the finally section without calling `exit` so it automatically calls the `repeat` footer also?

Comment: Use [`Continue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Continue) to proceed the next iteration.

Comment: @TLama Continue would not call finally, would it?

Comment: If the `if...end` is at the end of the `try` section, won't it just fall through to the `finally` by definition (assuming you remove the `exit`)? Or is there really other code between the `if... end` and the `finally`?

Comment: @mbratch there is more that's why I'm calling the `exit`. Haven't tried the continue yet... Will give it a try in a few.

Comment: Just remove the `exit`. It should automatically step into the `finally` on every iteration without you needing to do anything.

Comment: It would be helpful if your original question more faithfully represented the logic in ways that are significant to the scenario and solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`Continue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Continue) to proceed to the next iteration. The code in the `finally` part of the `try..finally` block is designed to be always executed, so even if you force skip to the next iteration:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  repeat
    TryAgain := False;
    try
      if SomeCondition then
      begin
        TryAgain := True;
        // this will proceed the finally block and go back to repeat
        Continue;
      end;
      // code which would be here will execute only if SomeCondition
      // is False, because calling Continue will skip it
    finally
      // code in this block is executed always
    end;
  until
    not TryAgain;
end;
```

But the very same logic you can write simply this way:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  repeat
    TryAgain := False;
    try
      if SomeCondition then
      begin
        TryAgain := True;
      end
      else
      begin
        // code which would be here will execute only if SomeCondition
        // is False
      end;
    finally
      // code in this block is executed always
    end;
  until
    not TryAgain;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't have to `call` finally. Simply removing the `exit` should allow it to automatically run the code in the `finally` at the end of every loop iteration. Here's code to demonstrate:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  i, j, Dummy: Integer;
  TryAgain: Boolean;

begin
  i := 0;
  Dummy := 0;
  TryAgain := True;
  repeat
    try
      for j := 0 to 200 do
        Dummy := Dummy + 1;
    finally
      Inc(i);
    end;
    TryAgain := (i < 10);
  until not TryAgain;
  WriteLn(i);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

If the `finally` was not executed at the end of every iteration, the `repeat` would never end, because `i` is only incremented in the `finally`, and if it wasn't being executed the terminating condition would never be met. Instead, it exits and outputs `11`, which indicates the `finally` is being run once per iteration of the `repeat` loop. (It outputs `11` instead of `10` because the `finally` executes an extra time.)